# Column ContentType does not exist.It may have been deleted by another user while adding/updating the list item

Tags: list, list-template

Need some taughts/help here.

I have taken the list template from WSS 2007 and then uploaded the same to the SharePoint 2013. That too after changing the ProductVersion from 3 to 4. After the list was successfully created using the same template,when am trying to add / edit the list item I got this error. “Column ‘ContentType’ does not exist.It may have been deleted by another user.”

I have created a Contentype column as suggested in blogs but this **only works** if i create a new item and then try to save or edit it

but doesnt work on exisitng items that that was created using the template.

I can view item but when i click edit i get this error:

```
Application error when access /sites/dev/Lists/xxx/EditForm.aspx, Error=Value cannot be null.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetProviderName(String fullName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.IsEncodedClaim(String value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PickerEntity.get_Claim()
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is it a user type column?

Comment: Hi Ruslan, Can you elaborate please?

Comment: If it is a user column, then there is mabe a problem with user values. The SPFiledUserValue is still lookup value, that uses the "Users and Groups" List. So if there are no elements(users) with same id, then SPFiledUserValue can not get the SPUser and cannot get Login.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to resolve this issue:

1. Enable "Allow Content type" in list settings
2. Create a SLT named `ContentType` and then hid it from all the forms if necessary